# suffers when using ibm wid (websphere integration developer), any advises?

Tags: websphere, wid

I joined a company who uses WID as the develop tool, I am new to wid, but i feels pain when using it for a reason:

every time i change or create a jsp file or java file or configuration file, if i want to see the the outcomes, i need to restart the wid server or republish the resources, and it takes a whole lot of time, i feel that 50% of my working time is waiting the server to start.

any one have any tips to reduce the waiting time?

I found a few by myself:

1. we can edit the css file in the deployed folder, and refresh the page, we can see the changes right away
2. so as the jsp files

what about java files? and xml config files? do i need to restart the wid server everytime i make a change?

I will be really appreciate your help, because i may not need to work overtime often because of your tips.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WID is primarily an integration tool built on top of RAD. It is predominantly used for SCA components and assembling them.

Try this for a start

Turn off auto publish

Turn of auto build

These two guidelines applies to RAD too.

By doing this you would save a good amount of time.

HTH

Manglu